# XML Transformation with labels using a stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, label, transformation

I have this part of a XML from pubmed:

```
<Abstract>

<AbstractText Label="BACKGROUND" NlmCategory="BACKGROUND"> one </AbstractText> 

<AbstractText Label="METHODS" NlmCategory="METHODS"> two </AbstractText>  

<AbstractText Label="RESULTS" NlmCategory="RESULTS"> three </AbstractText> 

<AbstractText Label="CONCLUSIONS" NlmCategory="CONCLUSIONS"> four</AbstractText>  

</Abstract>
```

Depending on the article there is different number labels (range 0-4). The result of the transformation shall be:

**one, two, three, four**

I used this XSL:

```
<COL>
<DATA>
<xsl:value-of select="abstract" />
</DATA>
</COL>
```

Unfortunately this only works if there are no labels and the abstract is provided directly under "abstract" . How do I have to modify this exerpt of the XSL to make it transfer everything that's mentioned under "abstract"?

Cheers 
vier.gewinnt

Comment: Can you please post your desired output? This is helpful to people providing answers as they can tailor them better to your requirements.

Comment: sure. I'm using Filemaker and import the xml. At the end I want the content of all labels in one field of the database, separated by commas. Would be great if someone could help.

Comment: So `<COL><DATA>one,two,three,four</DATA></COL>`?

Comment: rather  <COL><DATA>background, methods, results, conclusions</DATA></COL>

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that may work for you:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Abstract">
        <COL>
            <DATA>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
            </DATA>
        </COL>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AbstractText">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Label"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applying this to your input yields:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<COL>
    <DATA>BACKGROUND,METHODS,RESULTS,CONCLUSIONS,</DATA>
</COL>
```

Comment: It seems that you haven't run your proposed solution, otherwise you wouldn't say it produces the result you provide in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

**This short and *correct* transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <COL>
    <DATA>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </DATA>
  </COL>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*/*">
  <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">, </xsl:if>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@Label"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Abstract>
    <AbstractText Label="BACKGROUND" NlmCategory="BACKGROUND">one</AbstractText>
    <AbstractText Label="METHODS" NlmCategory="METHODS">two</AbstractText>
    <AbstractText Label="RESULTS" NlmCategory="RESULTS">three</AbstractText>
    <AbstractText Label="CONCLUSIONS" NlmCategory="CONCLUSIONS">four</AbstractText>
</Abstract>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<COL>
   <DATA>BACKGROUND, METHODS, RESULTS, CONCLUSIONS</DATA>
</COL>
```